# Unit testing apache httpconfig

Tags: apache, unit-testing, httpd.conf

I have a big, complex config file for httpd, which contains many reverse proxy blocks, redirects, IP whitelists and aliases.

Is it possible to run unit tests against this config file?

i.e.

1. Request to /account/login should be sent to the reverse proxy loginserver.example.com
2. Request to /admin should be served from /var/www/html/content if the IP of the client is 192.168.1.10
3. Request to /admin should give response code 403 if the IP of the client is 192.168.1.100
4. Request to /old/page should give a 301 redirect

My current process is integration testing which requires that I run a full server, and have all of the reverse proxies running, and it's difficult to test ip whitelists. I'm looking to automate all of that without all of the dependencies.

An ideal solution would have to hook deeply into apache, so that it can see the routing decisions made - an http client wouldn't know that the request was served by a reverse proxy. Also, the request to /admin would only return a 200 if there was actually content in the location (which there won't be while testing) so the system would only test that apache would serve content from the location, not require that there's actually content there.

Comment: Excuse my confusion, are you asking for configuration bits on how to do that, or how to test if your server is doing that?

Comment: Neither, really. I already have both of those. I'm looking for something which would allow me to 'unit test' the config. So I pass my current config file to 'something' and then I can confirm that my requests 'do the right thing' like I would when unit testing code.

Comment: ohh, I see. I think that "something" could perfectly be a separate VirtualHost with an "Include" pointing to a single file, for instance, and that file is the one in which you will specify your different set of directives to test. It will take a graceful restart for each modification, if you want something to use without restart, I'm afraid it will have to be .htaccess which will make it all more complicated.

Comment: I guess that would work for the simple cases, but wouldn't handle any strange interactions between various parts. Also I wouldn't be able to see reverse proxy requests. The 'something' I'm imagining would have to be very tightly hooked into Apache to inspect what it does.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

1. install bats - https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core
2. install docker - https://docs.docker.com
3. install host-manager - https://github.com/macmade/host-manager

Example BATS test suite:

**EDITED TO INCLUDE DUMMY LOGIN SERVER AND WEB ROOT**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

setup () {
 #change port and volumes accordingly 
 docker run -d -h -v /directory/with/apache/conf/for/simulation:/opt/docker/etc/httpd/conf.d loginserver.example.com --name reverse webdevops/base:ubuntu-16.04
 docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /directory/for/200:/app -v /directory/with/apache/conf:/opt/docker/etc/httpd/conf.d  --name web --link="reverse" webdevops/base:ubuntu-16.04
 #if you need a host name
 host-manager -add website.host.name 127.0.0.1
 docker run -d
}

@test "Request to /account/login should be sent to the reverse proxy loginserver.example.com" {
 result="$(curl -I http://website.host.name/account/login | sed '4q;d')" 
 [ "$result" -eq "Location: http://loginserver.example.com" ]
}

@test "Request to /admin should be served if the IP of the client is 192.168.1.10" {
 result="$(curl -I --header 'REMOTE_ADDR:192.168.1.10' http://website.host.name/admin | sed '1q;d' | cut -d$' ' -f2)" 
 [ "$result" -eq 200 ]
}

@test "Request to /admin should give response code 403 if the IP of the client is 192.168.1.100" {
 result="$(curl -I --header 'REMOTE_ADDR:192.168.1.100' http://website.host.name/admin | sed '1q;d' | cut -d$' ' -f2)" 
 [ "$result" -eq 403 ]
}

@test "Request to /old/page should give a 301 redirect" {
 result="$(curl -I --header 'REMOTE_ADDR:192.168.1.100' http://website.host.name/old/page | sed '1q;d' | cut -d$' ' -f2)" 
 [ "$result" -eq 301 ]
}


teardown() {
 docker kill web
 docker rm web
 docker kill reverse
 docker rm reverse
 host-manager -remove website.host.name
}
```

[bats-core](/questions/tagged/bats-core) [docker](/questions/tagged/docker)

Comment: Very nice - solves quite a few things. A minor issue is that the first test isn't a redirect, it's a reverse proxy, so the client wouldn't know where loginserver.example.com is. So I'm looking for something which can hook into apache and see what's happening with the routing inside it. Also, I wouldn't necessarily get a 200 from the second test unless I also deployed some content at the /admin location.

Comment: I have edited to add an additional login server as a dummy reverse proxy, plus a volume to deploy resources to return 200s. You may need to tweak. As you use more Docker containers you may want to switch to docker compose.

Comment: This is good, but still won't handle the reverse proxy - the client won't get back the 'Location:" header it would just get back the content from the reverse proxy. I suppose I could put 'special' content on the reverse proxy, and check the body, but by the time I've got that far, I'm not really doing a 'unit test' - I might as well run a full system.

Comment: Yes, scrap the location header for the test, and look for a 200 instead. You could set it up so that the only way it will get a 200 is if the proxy is running. Also you may want to put something in that delays the test execution until the web server is running (in detached mode it will exit before the server has completed startup)